# pandas apply and applymap functions are taking long time to run on large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, series

I have two functions applied on a dataframe

```
res = df.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(list(x)))  
res = res.applymap(lambda x: x.strip('"') if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

{{Update}} Dataframe has got almost 700 000 rows. This is taking much time to run.

How to reduce the running time?

Sample data :

```
   A        
 ----------
0 [1,4,3,c] 
1 [t,g,h,j]  
2 [d,g,e,w]  
3 [f,i,j,h] 
4 [m,z,s,e] 
5 [q,f,d,s]
```

output:

```
   A         B   C   D  E
-------------------------
0 [1,4,3,c]  1   4   3  c
1 [t,g,h,j]  t   g   h  j
2 [d,g,e,w]  d   g   e  w
3 [f,i,j,h]  f   i   j  h
4 [m,z,s,e]  m   z   s  e
5 [q,f,d,s]  q   f   d  s
```

This line of code `res = df.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(list(x)))` takes items from a list and fill one by one to each column as shown above. There will be almost 38 columns.

Comment: Can you add more sample data?

Comment: yes i have added the sample data

Comment: <<<<UPDATE>>>  there are 7 lakh rows

Comment: People outside India don't use measurements like lakh, so please don't use them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think:

```
res = df.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(list(x)))
```

should be changed to:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].values.tolist())
print (df1)
   0  1  2  3
0  1  4  3  c
1  t  g  h  j
2  d  g  e  w
3  f  i  j  h
4  m  z  s  e
5  q  f  d  s
```

And second if not mixed columns values - numeric with strings:

```
cols = res.select_dtypes(object).columns
res[cols] = res[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('"'))
```

Comment: @qwww - pandas then cannot use vestorized solutions, so it is reason for slow. Pandas best working if same columns types.

Comment: ohh.. so it is better if I convert everything into object type?

Comment: I think yes, `object` is obviusly `string`, so `df = df.astype(str)` should help. There is only one thing - `NAN`s are convert to strings too.

Comment: ohh if NaN s are converted, it will cause issue right?

Comment: It dependas of data, one possible solution is `df.stack().astype(str).unstack()` - it convert all values without `NaN`s

Comment: i tried to remove all columns with nan only using df= df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')..but it is not working,,i ahve some columns with full values as nan only

Comment: @qwww - So it means there are no missing values, but string NaN. It is possible check by `print (df.head().apply(type)` - for missing values you should get `float`, for strings `str`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174864/discussion-between-qwww-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

Late reply perhaps, but for people like me who stumble on this topic with the same question, it may be nonetheless worth adding what I found.

I used the swifter library. An apply function on a Pandas dataframe goes at least twice as fast, it also consumes less RAM:

```
import pandas as pd
import swifter

# then add .swifter between df and .apply, as in so...
res = df.swifter.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(list(x)))
```

And that's all. It worked really well for me. It also includes a status bar in the terminal which is really helpful as well.

I got the solution from: https://towardsdatascience.com/do-you-use-apply-in-pandas-there-is-a-600x-faster-way-d2497facfa66